# Change timestamp interval to smaller steps

Tags: r, date

I have a column in my data set that starts from 1483225200 to 1545346800 with steps of 86400 (one day in seconds) This is because I used the date to numeric converter `as.POSIXlt`. Because it is exactly 720 days, I would like to change the interval to 1. That the result would be ranged from 1 to 720. Is this possible?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes it is possible, please share the exact structure of your data set to allow us to help you

Comment: Do you need to conserve the times, or is it acceptable to replace the column with a vector containing 1 to 720, e.g. using `data$time <- seq(1,720)`?

Comment: `'data.frame': 1025234 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ orig_acct     : int  4749 1360 7430 5758 1051 6177 7513 6962 6736 4027 ...
 $ bene_acct     : int  9686 9006 2599 7197 9840 8750 9883 5883 6908 8399 ...
 $ base_amt      : num  96.6 101.8 95.5 110 93.9 ...
 $ tran_timestamp: num  1.48e+09 1.48e+09 1.48e+09 1.48e+09 1.48e+09 ...
 $ is_sar        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ alert_id      : int  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...`

Comment: I am new to this, The formatting is quite bad sorry

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale your values by subtracting the min and divide by the range between min and max to get values between 0 and 1.

Then multiply this value by 720 to get a range from 0 to 720 (or use `0:720` for an ordered column of date).

```
df <- data.frame(time = seq(1483225200, 1545346800, 86400))
df$interval <- (df$time - min(df$time)) / (max(df$time) - min(df$time))
df$range <- df$interval*720
```

Comment: Thanks, I have around 1 million observations, there are around 1500 observations with the same amount of seconds, how does that work?

Comment: Two same values are transformed the same way